# How does $\left(\log \sqrt x\right)^2 = \frac 14(\log x)^2\;?$

Tags: logarithms

So as the title says it all:

> How does $\;\left(\log \sqrt x\right)^2 = \frac 14(\log x)^2 \;?$

To be specific, why the removal of root, and how do we get 4 in denominator?

Comment: In general $\log(a^b)=b\log a$.

Comment: I think that the RHS (logx/2)^2 actually mean $((1/2)\log x)^2$.  This is equal to the LHS.

Comment: Well, thank you. Its now cleared! I hope someone edits the title with MathJax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recall: $$\log\left(a^b\right) = b\log a$$

Here, that means that $$\log (\sqrt x) = \log x^{1/2} = \frac 12 \log x$$

So $$\left(\log \sqrt x\right)^2 = \underbrace{\left(\frac {\log x}2\right)^2= \frac {(\log x)^2}{2^2}}_{\large \left(\frac ab\right)^c = \frac{a^c}{b^c}} =\frac 14(\log x)^2$$